# I want to call 'sentMessage' and 'phoneCall' method in my application but when we call these my application will be crash

Tags: android, android-adapter

****/this is my main activity where we add picures, name and phone numbers of the different person****.......................................................................

```
package com.example.customlistview;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView listview;
    TextView call,sms,myphone;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        listview=findViewById(R.id.listview);
        List<String> name=new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> phone=new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> call=new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> sms=new ArrayList<>();
        myphone=findViewById(R.id.phone);
        List<Integer> img=new ArrayList<>();
        img.add(R.drawable.img1);
        img.add(R.drawable.img2);
        img.add(R.drawable.img3);
        name.add("Ahmad");
        name.add("Ali");
        name.add("Riaz");
        call.add("call");
        call.add("call");
        call.add("call");
        sms.add("sms");
        sms.add("sms");
        sms.add("sms");
        phone.add("03053424234");
        phone.add("03453243432");
        phone.add("03348586753");
        MyAdapter adapter=new MyAdapter(this,name,call,sms,img,phone);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    }
```

this is my adapter class where we override all method and i am trying to call the phonecall and sentmessage**...........................................................

```
     public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    List<String> name;
    List<String> call;
    List<String> sms;
    List<String> phone;
    List<Integer> img;
    Context context;

    public MyAdapter(@NonNull Context context, List<String> name, List<String> call, List<String> sms,
                     List<Integer> img, List<String> phone) {
        super(context, R.layout.mylayout, name);
        this.name = name;
        this.img = img;
        this.call = call;
        this.sms = sms;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.context = context;
    }
```

Blockquote

```
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        // return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.mylayout, parent, false);
        ImageView image = view.findViewById(R.id.image);
        TextView name1 = view.findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView call1 = view.findViewById(R.id.call);
        TextView sms1 = view.findViewById(R.id.sms);
        TextView phone1 = view.findViewById(R.id.phone);
        name1.setText(name.get(position));
        call1.setText(call.get(position));
        sms1.setText(sms.get(position));
        phone1.setText(phone.get(position));
        image.setImageResource(img.get(position));
        return view;
    }
    public void sentMessage(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("smsto:"));  // This ensures only SMS apps respond
        intent.putExtra("sms_body", "");
        //intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, attachment);
        if (intent.resolveActivity(context.getPackageManager()) != null) {
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
        public void phoneCall(View v)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + 123));
            if (intent.resolveActivity(context.getPackageManager()) != null) {
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        }

}
```

Comment: fix code formatting and show your crash stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

Try this to send message:

```
public void openMessageIntent(String number, String message){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("sms"+number));
    intent.putExtra("sms_body", message);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

for call intent

```
public void openCallIntent(String number ){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel"+number));
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For call You must get permissions in manifest

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>`

and you can use autolinks from XML

`android:autoLink="phone"`